# Running Sh Script Post Login via SSH / Console

Tags: bash, authentication, ssh

I need to run a bash script for all users when a login is obtained, in either local console access or SSH.

I know about ~/.profile, however I need this to run if the user bypasses the profile during login with "noprofile". It basically needs to run in every single possible context.

Is there a particular folder/file that executes every time a user successfully logs on that I can tap into?

Comment: why do u want to do this?

Comment: Essentially a trap account. Need it to confirm a successfull login but immediately tag the remote IP and log the account back out. Part of a research project I'm working on.

Comment: what if the user does not use bash at all?

Comment: The user has /bin/bash/ on their profile. Any account used is set up with that. Im working through each hurdle one by one. This would seem to be another. So yeah if they specify zsh or any alternative, this still needs to trigger. Id rather not do it through syslog as id like it to be instant.

Comment: for ssh you can use /etc/ssh/sshrc (see the sshd manual) .. for console you should look on FAKE_SHELL configuration option in login.defs  (see login manual). however this question is better suited for [su], [sf] or maybe [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Sorins comment. Successfully done using the following link.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sshd.8.html

LOGIN PROCESS
     When a user successfully logs in, sshd does the following:

```
       1.   If the login is on a tty, and no command has been specified, prints last login
            time and /etc/motd (unless prevented in the configuration file or by
            ~/.hushlogin; see the FILES section).

       2.   If the login is on a tty, records login time.

       3.   Checks /etc/nologin; if it exists, prints contents and quits (unless root).

       4.   Changes to run with normal user privileges.

       5.   Sets up basic environment.

       6.   Reads the file ~/.ssh/environment, if it exists, and users are allowed to change
            their environment.  See the PermitUserEnvironment option in sshd_config(5).

       7.   Changes to user's home directory.

       8.   If ~/.ssh/rc exists, runs it; else if /etc/ssh/sshrc exists, runs it; otherwise
            runs xauth.  The “rc” files are given the X11 authentication protocol and cookie
            in standard input.  See SSHRC, below.

       9.   Runs user's shell or command.
```